# How do I get my encrypted private key converted?

Tags: encryption

```
"addr":              "typicalbitcoinaddress", 
"compressed":        true, 
"encrypted_privkey": "this  is my private key that is 96 characters long", 
"label":             "Wallet", 
"pubkey":            "Public key of the address",
"salt":              "random small set of digits not sure what this is"
```

I dont know how to convert my private key that is under "encrypted_privkey" (96 characters long) (Not sure what it is encrypted to) to a Wallet Import Format like to import it into blockchain.info....Any help on the process to convert this to a WIF private key would be greatly appreciated, I am unable to provide the private key of course...

Comment: Blockchain has [import instructions](https://blockchain.info/wallet/import-wallet) on their import page for `wallet.dat` files near the bottom. Assuming you are using Bitcoin-QT, which you should have mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, it would help if you mentioned what wallet you are using.